# CompilerInstance::setInvocation fails at runtime with: "pointer being freed was not allocate"

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, llvm-clang

I'm trying to use Clang and I'm having issues with its reference-counting mechanism.
Whenever I try to assign a CompilerInvocation to a CompilerInstance, at runtime I get an error:

```
clangjit(13823,0x7fff7646f310) malloc: *** error for object 0x103002c00: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

This is a minimal program that reproduces the issue:

```
#include <clang/Frontend/CompilerInstance.h>
#include <clang/Frontend/CompilerInvocation.h>

using namespace clang;
int main(int argc, const char* const *argv) {
    CompilerInstance* CI = new CompilerInstance();
    CI->setInvocation(new CompilerInvocation());
}
```

CompilerInstance internally does reference counting using:

```
IntrusiveRefCntPtr<CompilerInvocation> Invocation;
```

and the setter is defined as:

```
void CompilerInstance::setInvocation(CompilerInvocation *Value) {
  Invocation = Value;
}
```

(I have no control over either of these since they come from Clang).

This is the stack trace at the point of failure:

```
#0  0x00007fff8d097866 in __pthread_kill ()
#1  0x00007fff8df2635c in pthread_kill ()
#2  0x00007fff8d03ab1a in abort ()
#3  0x00007fff8485807f in free ()
#4  0x0000000100002678 in std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, void*> >::deallocate(std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, void*>*, unsigned long) [inlined] at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/memory:1632
#5  0x000000010000266c in std::__1::allocator_traits<std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, void*> > >::deallocate(std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, void*> >&, std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, void*>*, unsigned long) [inlined] at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/memory:1443
#6  0x0000000100002654 in std::__1::__tree<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >::destroy(std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, void*>*) at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__tree:1446
#7  0x0000000100002551 in ~__tree at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__tree:1433
#8  0x00000001000024f5 in ~__tree at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__tree:1432
#9  0x00000001000024d5 in ~set at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/set:398
#10 0x0000000100002325 in ~set at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/set:398
#11 0x00000001000022f5 in ~SmallSet at /Users/juancn/Downloads/clang+llvm-3.4.1-x86_64-apple-darwin10.9/include/llvm/ADT/SmallSet.h:31
#12 0x00000001000022c5 in ~SmallSet at /Users/juancn/Downloads/clang+llvm-3.4.1-x86_64-apple-darwin10.9/include/llvm/ADT/SmallSet.h:31
#13 0x000000010000229e in ~SetVector at /Users/juancn/Downloads/clang+llvm-3.4.1-x86_64-apple-darwin10.9/include/llvm/ADT/SetVector.h:37
#14 0x0000000100001de5 in ~SetVector at /Users/juancn/Downloads/clang+llvm-3.4.1-x86_64-apple-darwin10.9/include/llvm/ADT/SetVector.h:37
#15 0x0000000100001d55 in ~HeaderSearchOptions at /Users/juancn/Downloads/clang+llvm-3.4.1-x86_64-apple-darwin10.9/include/clang/Lex/HeaderSearchOptions.h:45
#16 0x0000000100001d25 in ~HeaderSearchOptions at /Users/juancn/Downloads/clang+llvm-3.4.1-x86_64-apple-darwin10.9/include/clang/Lex/HeaderSearchOptions.h:45
#17 0x0000000100001cf3 in llvm::RefCountedBase<clang::HeaderSearchOptions>::Release() const at /Users/juancn/Downloads/clang+llvm-3.4.1-x86_64-apple-darwin10.9/include/llvm/ADT/IntrusiveRefCntPtr.h:54
#18 0x0000000100001c45 in llvm::IntrusiveRefCntPtrInfo<clang::HeaderSearchOptions>::release(clang::HeaderSearchOptions*) at /Users/juancn/Downloads/clang+llvm-3.4.1-x86_64-apple-darwin10.9/include/llvm/ADT/IntrusiveRefCntPtr.h:89
#19 0x0000000100001c1d in llvm::IntrusiveRefCntPtr<clang::HeaderSearchOptions>::release() at /Users/juancn/Downloads/clang+llvm-3.4.1-x86_64-apple-darwin10.9/include/llvm/ADT/IntrusiveRefCntPtr.h:178
#20 0x0000000100001bd1 in ~IntrusiveRefCntPtr at /Users/juancn/Downloads/clang+llvm-3.4.1-x86_64-apple-darwin10.9/include/llvm/ADT/IntrusiveRefCntPtr.h:148
#21 0x0000000100001315 in ~IntrusiveRefCntPtr at /Users/juancn/Downloads/clang+llvm-3.4.1-x86_64-apple-darwin10.9/include/llvm/ADT/IntrusiveRefCntPtr.h:148
#22 0x0000000100001297 in ~CompilerInvocationBase at /Users/juancn/Downloads/clang+llvm-3.4.1-x86_64-apple-darwin10.9/include/clang/Frontend/CompilerInvocation.h:52
#23 0x0000000100254435 in clang::CompilerInstance::setInvocation(clang::CompilerInvocation*) ()
#24 0x0000000100000ea4 in main at /Users/juancn/projects/clangjit/clangjit/clangjit/main.cpp:7
```

What I don't understand is why setInvocation() is calling the destructor on CompilerInvocationBase which seems to be the reason of the failure (my C++ is a bit rusty, so it's quite likely that I missing something obvious).

**UPDATE:** I just found that just deleting the object causes the issue:

```
CompilerInvocation* CI = new CompilerInvocation;
delete CI;
```

So it looks like a bug in Clang. I still haven't found a way to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out (sort of). I was linking to clang binaries for OSX ([clang+llvm-3.4.1-x86_64-apple-darwin10.9](http://llvm.org/releases/3.4.1/clang+llvm-3.4.1-x86_64-apple-darwin10.9.tar.xz)) but it seems something was off with them.

I rebuilt Clang + LLVM from scratch and used the locally built libraries instead. That solved the issue.